# Using SSE to pass on data from other APIs in real time

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, server-sent-events

I want to make a real time visualization in which I have a flask application sending SSE to the HTML which is then doing its stuff. Visualization works totally fine. I am confused with respect to the SSE. There is a system which pings my application at '/data' to handover the data. Which I then want to transfer to the vis in the event stream.

```
import time, json
from flask import Flask, request, Response, render_template

app =Flask(__name__)

def data_stream(data):
    if data:
        yield 'data: {}\n\n'.format(json.dumps(data))
    else:
        yield 'data: {}\n\n'.format(json.dumps({'data': [{'lat':0, 'lg':0}]}))

@app.route('/data', methods =['GET','POST'])
def collect_data():
    data = {"data": [request.get_json()]}
    data_stream(data)
    return 'asd'


@app.route('/my_event_source', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def sse_request():
    return Response(data_stream(None), mimetype='text/event-stream')

@app.route('/')
def page():
    return render_template('map_vis.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data2 = []
    app.debug =True
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 8081)
```

I am unable to figure out a way to pass the data_stream function to Response because as of now it is simply calling data_stream(None) only i.e. I am getting `{'lat':0, 'lg':0}` in response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're using SSE like long polling or another AJAX-derived technique ; SSE is more useful as a stream, so once the SSE connection is established you need to keep the data sending function 'alive' and to make
it sending data whenever you need it.

So, I would do that:

```
import Queue
data_queue = Queue.Queue()

def data_stream():
    while True:
        data = data_queue.get()
        yield 'data: {}\n\n'.format(json.dumps(data))
```

When sending data through SSE, I would just put data in the queue:

```
def sse_request():
    r = Response(data_stream(),  mimetype='text/event-stream')
    data_queue.put({'data': [{'lat':0, 'lg':0}]})
    return r

def collect_data():
    data_queue.put({"data": [request.get_json()]})
    ...
```

The only thing is that writing it this way will cause the `while`
loop to block the server. So you need to use something additional, like
[gevent](http://www.gevent.org) or [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net).
There are lots of examples how to combine Flask with those.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It seems to be working now. I think it was more of a question about system architecture. Queue was the catch!